# How to get ignite CacheEvent for ClientCache

Tags: ignite

I want to get the CacheEvent for update on the ignite ClientCach is made.

I have 2 Server connected and replicating data between of them.

First application is connecting using the IgniteClient(TcpClient) 
'Ignition.startClient()' and publishing the update to ignite instance.

I would like the second Instance to  connect to remote Server and get an update when the cache is being updated.

currently this is working only for updates from Ignite with this :
Ignition.start()

Answer (score 1):

Continuous queries could help you https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries You need run query from second client instance and subscribe for interested events.

To get cache events, you might try remote event listener https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events#section-remote-events

Comment: Tried the option for remote events but no success . can it be a difference when using ClientCache<Long, Object> or  IgniteCache<Long, Object> 
I am using the Client cache for that

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up thin and thick clients. Do you want to get events on thin client? I don't think it's possible right now, you'd rather try to start Ignite in client mode that has all feature set: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setClientMode-boolean-

Comment: I have tried both but probably misses some configurations . I configured both server and client to throw events. No success their

Comment: Could you please upload your project to github that I could check it?

Comment: i have solved This issue when using IgniteCache API ( not the Thin JAVA Client) another issue is consumer was must be in Server Mode.

Comment: i have sucseed with the event publishing but the throughput was very slow when using IgniteCache(GridAtomicCache)  vs ClientCache(TcpClientCache), do you know how i can increase the throughput ?

Comment: With the same config and disabled events do you see different throughput? If yes, try to get JFR or use any other profiling tool to compare results and find the bottleneck, because there should not be much difference.